# Saltar cajas de texto al escribir una letra en HTML, JS

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<form method="POST">

  <input type="text" name="caja1"><br>
  <input type="text" name="caja2"><br>
  <input type="text" name="caja3"><br>

</form>
```

Quisiera que al escribir una letra en la caja1 automáticamente me posicione el foco en la caja2 y al escribir una letra en la caja2 me posicione el foco en la caja3.

Comment: No tengo un ejemplo de como puedo hacerlo, no encontré ningún código al respecto.

Answer (score 2):

> La solucion la plantee con `jQuery`, necesitas incluirlo en tu `html` para que funcione correctamente. Acá edité la respuesta, tenes que guardar el `js` como `js.js` en la misma carpeta donde esté el html, en otro caso tendrias que cambiar la direccion del archivo en la linea `<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>`

```js
// Cuando se cargue el documento, se activa la funcion de adentro
$(document).ready(function(){
 // Pongo el focus en la primer caja  
 $("#caja1").focus()
 

 //La funcion keypress es activada cuando se presiona una letra en el input
 // Le indico que cuando detecte el ingreso de un valor, pase el focus a la caja 2
 $("#caja1").keypress(function(){
   $("#caja2").focus()
 })

 // Analogo al anterior, esta vez paso el focus al input 3 si el keypress se hizo
 //en el input 2
 $("#caja2").keypress(function(){
   $("#caja3").focus()
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
<form method="POST">

  <input type="text" id="caja1"><br>
  <input type="text" id="caja2"><br>
  <input type="text" id="caja3"><br>

</form>
```

Comment: De hecho y técnicamente esta planteada de forma exacta con JQuery

Comment: jaja quise poner jQuery, hasta le indique que cargue el ``cdn``, error de tipear y mirar tv a la vez

Comment: @AgustinG. El ejemplo funciona aquí, pero no me funciona cuando lo llevo a mi servidor local, incluso descargue la librería Jquery, podrías ayudarme ?

Comment: claro, me compartes el codigo completo de ambos archivos?

Comment: @IsraelNinaVargas ya edité la respuesta, espero que ahora te funcione correctamente, cualquier cosa me dices

Comment: @AgustinG. Muchas gracias, el ejemplo esta funcionando correctamente, gracias por la ayuda bro

Comment: me alegra, recorda darle al tilde verde para marcar que la respuesta te sirvió como correcta, lo agradeceria